# Spring Data Query Construction Using Method Name and Object Parameter

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

I was wondering if it was possible to not need the @Query annotation and let Spring Data construct the JPA Query based on my method name and method parameters for the below entity relationship.  I want to retrieve a list of ItemLocations that are related to a particular Item.  I tried the below signature and it didn't work without the @Query.  Is it also more proper (efficient/effective) to pass in the Item.id instead of the Item object itself?

Spring Data Version: 1.3.4.RELEASE

**Working Spring Data Repository API:**

```
@Query("FROM ItemLocation where item = ?")
public List<ItemLocation> getAllItemLocations(Item item);
```

**Desired Spring Data Repository API:**

```
public List<ItemLocation> findAllItemLocations(Item item);
```

**JPA Enties:**

```
 @Entity
    public class ItemLocation {
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="fk_item_id")
        public Item getItem() {
            return this.item;
        }
        public void setItem(Item item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        public long getId() {
           return this.id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        private Item item;
        private long id;
    }

    @Entity
    public class Item {
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="item", orphanRemoval=true)
        @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST})
        public Set<ItemLocation> getItemLocationList() {
            return this.itemLocationList;
        }
        public void setItemLocationList(Set<ItemLocation> list) {
            this.itemLocationList = list;
        }
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        public long getId() {
           return this.id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        private Set<ItemLocation> itemLocationList
            = new HashSet<ItemLocation>();
        private long id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<ItemLocation> findAllByItem(Item item);
```

(in repository ItemLocationRepository)